# spark change DF schema column rename from dot to underscore

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with columns names that has `dot`.
Example : df.printSchema

```
user.id_number
user.name.last
user.phone.mobile
```

etc and I want to rename the schema by replacing the `dot` with `_`.

```
user_id_number
user_name_last
user_phone_mobile
```

Note: the input data for this DF is JSON format (with nonrelational like `NoSQL`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either **`.map,.withColumnRenamed`**  to replace `.` with `_`

**`Example:`**

```
val df=Seq(("1","2","3")).toDF("user.id_number","user.name.last","user.phone.mobile")
df.toDF(df.columns.map(x =>x.replace(".","_")):_*).show()

//using replaceAll
df.toDF(df.columns.map(x =>x.replaceAll("\\.","_")):_*).show()
//+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
//|user_id_number|user_name_last|user_phone_mobile|
//+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
//|             1|             2|                3|
//+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

**`2. Using selectExpr:`**

```
val expr=df.columns.map(x =>col(s"`${x}`").alias(s"${x}".replace(".","_")).toString)

df.selectExpr(expr:_*).show()
//+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
//|user_id_number|user_name_last|user_phone_mobile|
//+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
//|             1|             2|                3|
//+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

**`3.Using .withColumnRenamed:`**

```
df.columns.foldLeft(df){(tmpdf,col) =>tmpdf.withColumnRenamed(col,col.replace(".","_"))}.show()
//+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
//|user_id_number|user_name_last|user_phone_mobile|
//+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
//|             1|             2|                3|
//+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
```